# in the 4th line, why cant I say i instead of numArr[i] and is there another way to write this?

Tags: javascript, function

I just dont understand how the i does not hold the number itself. I know usually brackets after something refers to the index. I am confused here.

```
function sumArray(numArr){
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++){
        total += numArr[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following line.

```js
function sumArray(numArr){
  let sum = 0;
  for(let v of numArr) {
    sum += v;
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(sumArray([1, 0, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense now. I know of that method but when its in front of me I can see why because its specifying v of numArr. But This doesnt fully answer my question.

Comment: Ok, let me explain. @DawnOfTheTacos
Here, "v" is the value of an element of numArray and it means numArray[i].

Comment: I see @Senior Web Engineer. That answers that

Answer (score 0):

> I just dont understand how the i does not hold the number itself. I
> know usually brackets after something refers to the index. I am
> confused here.

This is because you are using `for` statement and in a `for` statement the `i` is a counter variable and always have the index not the value of the array at that index. If you need value in `i` use `forEach` as below or use `for..in` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in))  as mentioned in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67831282/1188322)

```js
function sumArray(numArr){
    let total = 0;
    numArr.forEach (i=>{total += i});
    return total;
}

console.log(sumArray([1,2,3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best tool to sum up the array is [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Reduce is the best tool if your final result gonna be a single value, It could be an array, an object, or even a single sum value(as in this case).

No need to care about the **index** and the **variable** that store the sum (reduce do it internally)

```js
function sumArray(numArr) {
  return numArr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
}

console.log( sumArray([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add then you can use this instead.

```js
function sumArray(numArr) {
  let total = numArr.reduce((x, y) => x + y)
  console.log(total)
}
sumArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

This is the easiest way to do summation. Basically `reduce()` reduces the any array passed to a single value. It will execute a function for every element from left to right. At least that is what I know. If this solution is your answer, mark it with the tick on the left.